# Get filenames of RAR achive via smbclient

Tags: smb, winrar

From linux server I want to get the list of filenames in RAR archive which located in remote windows server.
Here is my command:

```
smbclient -U username%password '\\IP\D$\' --directory '\Backup_Logs' -c '"%programfiles(x86)%\WinRAR\unrar.exe" l file.rar'
```

After running this in linux server the answer is this:

> %programfiles(x86)%\WinRAR\unrar.exe: command not found

But I'm sure that I have Winrar installed on windows machine...
Where is my mistake or how I can reach my target in another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited sets of operations you can use with the `--command` option.
They are listed under the Operations header on https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html

Try using `smbmount` before using the local unrar command on the Linux system.